# Get subclass properties from list of superclass

Tags: c#, reflection, type-conversion, polymorphism

I have a method that will convert a `List<T>` into a TSV string with a header row and will only have rows which have a value for any item in the list. What I was doing previously was getting the type of `T` and working off that. My problem now, it that my list will no longer contain an item of type `T`, but something that derives from the type of the list. So doing `typeof(T).GetProperties()` will no longer work because that's looking at the parent type and not the child type.

```
public static string ListToTSVString<T>(List<T> items)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);

    // Get only properties that actually have a value in the list.
    var propsDictionary =
        properties.ToDictionary(p => p, p => items.Select(l => p.GetValue(l)).ToArray())
            .Where(pair => pair.Value.Any(o => o != null))
            .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);

    // Header row
    builder.AppendLine(string.Join("\t", propsDictionary.Keys.Select(x => x.GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyAttribute>().PropertyName)));

    // Body of TSV
    foreach (T item in items)
    {
        builder.AppendLine(string.Join("\t", propsDictionary.Keys.Select(x => x.GetValue(item))));
    }

    // Remove new line character
    return builder.ToString().TrimEnd();
}
```

As an example of something I am passing in is:

```
public class CustomObject
{
    public string GUID { get; set; }
}

public class Referral : CustomObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I'd then call this with a: `List<CustomObject> objects = new List<CustomObject> { new Referral() { Name = "Jimenemex" } }`.

I'm trying to get the TSV string to now contain only the declared properties on the `Referral` type and not the `CustomObject` type. Before I was only working with an object that doesn't inherit from anything so this was working nicely.

I've tried to use `items.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0]`, but that would still get the `CustomObject` type.

Comment: How about `item.GetType()`? Each item could be a `Referral` or just a `CustomObject`, so you have to reflect on the type of each item.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `typeof(T)` you can use the type of item stored in items collections. See following code (use `ConcurrentDictionary` to cache the properties only)

```
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<Type,  PropertyInfo[]> typeProperties = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type,  PropertyInfo[]>();
    private static PropertyInfo[] GetProperties(Type type)
    {
        if (!typeProperties.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            typeProperties[type] = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
        }
        
        return typeProperties[type];
    }
    
    public static string ListToTSVString<T>(List<T> items)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        PropertyInfo[] properties = GetProperties(items.First().GetType());

        // Get only properties that actually have a value in the list.
        var propsDictionary =
            properties.ToDictionary(p => p, p => items.Select(l => p.GetValue(l)).ToArray())
                .Where(pair => pair.Value.Any(o => o != null))
                .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);

        // Header row
        builder.AppendLine(string.Join("\t", propsDictionary.Keys.Select(x => x.GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyAttribute>().PropertyName)));

        // Body of TSV
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            builder.AppendLine(string.Join("\t", propsDictionary.Keys.Select(x => x.GetValue(item))));
        }

        // Remove new line character
        return builder.ToString().TrimEnd();
    }
```

You can see this fiddle - https://dotnetfiddle.net/HtnFkG created for demo your scenario.

Comment: `items.First()` won't work if the list contains a mix of types. If the first item is a `Referral`, it will attempt to get `Referral`'s properties from all items; if there are any `CustomObject` instances, it will throw when it gets to the first one of that type. The property list has to be retrieved within the loop. Fortunately, this solution memoizes that result.

Comment: Agreed, that's why I started adding dictionary to catch the properties (retrieved by reflection) so that the logic can be moved into foreach loop if OP requires based on having mixed types in `items` collection.